# How to get back focus on my Swing Java GUI running on a Solaris machine?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, focus, solaris

Hi guys i am working on a java swings GUI on the Solaris platform,  I want my application to have the focus at all times and change only when I click a button I am having to do it for a reqirement which might actually seem very stupid... Please let me know if there are any simple solutions for this one :P

Answer (score 1):

From [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html):

> Exactly how a window gains the focus depends on the windowing system. There is no foolproof way, across all platforms, to ensure that a window gains the focus. On some operating systems, such as Microsoft Windows, the front window usually becomes the focused window. In these cases, the Window.toFront method moves the window to the front, thereby giving it the focus. However, on other operating systems, such as Solaris™ Operating System, the window manager may choose the focused window based on cursor position, and in these cases the behavior of the Window.toFront method is different.

Keeping that in mind, you'll need to find a way to give your application focus in Java that works with your window manager. You can try setting the window as "always on top", but again, it is still up to the window manager to respect that wish. If you can do that, you can schedule a `TimerTask` that will periodically request focus to your window. This is incredibly annoying though, and suggesting it makes me feel dirty.